# OS X Finder: Why does it take less time to copy files in succession than to do so all at once?

Tags: macos, finder, hardware, filesystem, data-transfer

**Example:**

- Select 10x2GB files, then drag and drop to another location.
- Drag and drop each 2GB file to the location individually, in succession (10 times).

**I’ve tested this across multiple OS X versions and Apple computers, and the latter example *always* executes faster.**

- Why’s the drag and drop sequential fashion faster?
- That said, why doesn’t Finder just execute batch operations in the same manner? I must be missing something(s)…

**Note:** This is a question that teeters on the edge of not being within the bounds of this site, yet nonetheless, one worth asking :)

---

The results are the same regardless of the order (batch/manual) in which it's performed.

Comment: Specify in your original question if you are running a multi-processor: ` > About This Mac > System Report... > Hardware`.

Comment: Specify in your original question how you avoided between your 2 first copies to take advantage of the system cache?

Comment: @danielAzuelos Yes…quad core 2.6Ghz i7. Same result on a dual core iMac from 07.

Comment: Then if your system is nearly empty (just the Kernel, the Finder plus a few screenfull of standard daemons) parallel operations might perform nearly 4 times faster than sequential ones.

Comment: Why have you not answered daniel Azuelos question, "_Specify in your original question how you avoided between your 2 first copies to take advantage of the system cache?_"? Are you rebooting between the batch test and individual files test? Are you copying just to another place on the internal drive or to an external drive? If external, what type is it?

Comment: @user3439894 bc there’s a false assumption that I only tested in that order (batch first, manual second). I’ve edited the Q to clarify that the order doesn’t matter.

Comment: I'm not assuming anything, just trying to ascertain whether or not you rebooted in between the different methods of copying the files. Also are you copying just to another place on the internal drive or to an external drive and what type of drives are they, HDD or SSD etc. Additionally, just how much faster is "faster" and how are you timing the operations.

Comment: Done few quick tests myself.  I don't see any significant difference.  The 10 at once case appears to be done sequentially.   In my case, I tried SSD to SSD and SSD to HDD.  Both cases disk write MB/s and read MB/s were about the same showing cache not being used.  HDD case obviously limited by its speed ~100MB/s.  Used XRG & iStatMenus to display disk speeds.

Comment: @Gilby That's good info...What OSX are you running?

Comment: @njboot  I'm running 10.11.4

Answer (score 1):

I **think** in your example you are copying all files to the same disk. If the finder is trying to write to multiple places (or reading from multiple places) on the same hard drive, it will be slowed down by drive access times. It is easier (faster) to read (or write) one whole file at a time rather than ten files at the same time.

You can observe similar behavior if you are compressing video to a smaller codec. If you choose to export to the same disk that you are reading your source file from, your export will go much slower than exporting to another drive.

You could re-do your test using 3 separate disks (provided those disks were not being accessed across the same bus (USB3/Thunderbolt, etc.). That might be interesting to test.